# How to get fields in cassandra which are not fetched before

Tags: cassandra

I have a situation, I need to fetch only those fields from a Cassandra table which are not fetched before. So, I need to update it whenever I am fetching and next time the fields which were already fetched should not come in the list of rows.

I tried which an is_fetched field in the primary key, but then the primary key cannot be updated. Any solutions for this scenario?

Comment: Can you expand your question - does the list of fields depends on some "job ID", or something like? What is partition key:?

Comment: what library/language are you using?